# can anyone explain the use of nested static interface below

Tags: java, jdbc, log4j2

I was trying to use `jdbc appender` from `log4j2` for logging information to database. I came across this class for creating connection.

```
public class ConnectionFactory {
    //couldn't understand the logic for need of this interface
    private static interface Singleton {
        final ConnectionFactory INSTANCE = new ConnectionFactory();
    }

    private final DataSource dataSource;

    private ConnectionFactory() {
          //necessary connection creation for DataSource datasource
          //connection pooling is used here
    }

    public static Connection getDatabaseConnection() throws SQLException {
        return Singleton.INSTANCE.dataSource.getConnection();
    }
}
```

For getting the connection, all I have to do is call the `getDatabaseConnection()` class. And it works. But I cannot understand why I need to have the interface named Singleton. What would happen if I don't use it. And by don't use it, I mean, is not just deleting that code but also make other changes accordingly like make constructor public if necessary, `getDatabaseConnection()` non-static if necessary.

But is that interface named Singleton really used effectively here. I hope I would get cleared on this logic. And thank you.

Also this code is available from https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#JDBCAppender

Comment: Are you asking why ConnectionFactory is a singleton, or why the singleton is implemented using a nested interface?

Comment: @shmosel I don't know about OP but I'd love to know why is it implemented using a nested interface like that. Can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: @Voldemort https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization-on-demand_holder_idiom?wprov=sfla1

Answer (score 1):

Basically ConnectionFactory class is implementing singleton design pattern which is used to get only single object/bean of that class.You could study this pattern from various online resources and will understand this class is using Singleton with lazy initialization concept.

Simple definition:-

> Singleton pattern is a design solution where an application wants to
>   have one and only one instance of any class, in all possible scenarios
>   without any exceptional condition.

An implementation of the singleton pattern must:

1)Ensure that only one instance of the singleton class ever exists.

2)Provide global access to that instance.

Typically, this is done by:

1)Declaring all constructors of the class to be private.

2)Providing a static method that returns a reference to the instance.

Few Resources for your better understanding how to implement this design pattern:-
https://howtodoinjava.com/design-patterns/creational/singleton-design-pattern-in-java/

[https://dzone.com/articles/singleton-design-pattern](https://dzone.com/articles/singleton-design-pattern-%E2%80%93)

Comment: This answer doesn't really touch on the question "I am trying hard but cannot understand why I need to have the interface named Singleton".
@shmosel's comment on the question does answer this nicely though.

Comment: If you will read the answer carefully you will know it is saying same thing which @shmosel has provided in comment. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization-on-demand_holder_idiom means Singleton concept with lazy initialization only.

Comment: It doesn't, as far as I can tell. The important part is that, in order to defer the static initialization from start-up time to on-demand run time, the static property has to be a member of a nested static class. There's no mention of that in your answer: having the singleton be a member of the outer class means that it is created when the class is loaded, at start time.